# Google Maps different marker images for tapped and unselected state

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift4, google-maps-sdk-ios

is there a way to add an ID, a case or something similar, in order to set custom marker images for selected and unselected state?

I have multiple markers with different names/title, and i need that a specific type of marker has another image for selected and unselected state.

For example:

marker1 - marker_1_image

marker2 - marker_2_image

Atm I am only able to set 2 images with the right images but If I click on a marker it will hereditate the the specific type set on the ".contains" function.
I did a ".contains" function in order to find a specific string in a JSON response under the POI/location name. eg: currentAtmModel?.placeName?.contains("restaurant"), so markers with the name "restaurant" will be shown with a specific icon image.

I'm using the latest version of Google Maps SDK for iOS.

Here is my code:

```
var markersModel: [MarkersLocation] = [] {
        didSet {
            updateAllMarkers()
        }
    }

private func updateAllMarkers() {
        for selectedPOIMarker in markersModel {
            let currentPOIModel = selectedPOIMarker.location
            let latitude = currentPOIModel?.coordinates?.latitude
            let longitude = currentPOIModel?.coordinates?.longitude

            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude ?? 0, longitude: longitude ?? 0)

            if (currentPOIModel?.placeName?.contains("db")) ?? false {
                marker.icon = restaurantMarkerIcon(selected: false)
            } else {
                marker.icon = normalMarkerIcon(selected: false)
            }
            marker.map = googleMapsView
        }
    }

extension POILocatorViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        googleMapsView.selectedMarker = marker
        googleMapsView.animate(toLocation: marker.position)
        googleMapsView.selectedMarker?.icon = normalMarkerIcon(selected: true)
        googleMapsView.selectedMarker?.icon = restaurantMarkerIcon(selected: true)
        guard let markersModel = markersModel.filter({ $0.location?.coordinates?.latitude == marker.position.latitude && $0.location?.coordinates?.longitude == marker.position.longitude }).first else { return false }
        coordinatorDelegate?.poiLocatorViewController(self, didTap: markersModel, currentLocation: currentLocation)

        return true
    }
}

extension POILocatorViewController {
    func reloadMarker() {
        googleMapsView.selectedMarker?.icon = normalMarkerIcon(selected: false)
        googleMapsView.selectedMarker?.icon = restaurantMarkerIcon(selected: false)
        googleMapsView.selectedMarker = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to assign a unique identifier to the marker to identify the tapped marker?

Comment: @HardikS yes correct, how can I solve this?

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you will add a marker to `GMSMapView`, you can assign a unique identifier to `GMSMarker` using it's `zIndex` property to identify the marker.

```
 let marker = GMSMarker()
 marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
 marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude ?? 0, longitude: longitude ?? 0)

 if (currentPOIModel?.placeName?.contains("db")) ?? false {
     marker.icon = restaurantMarkerIcon(selected: false)
 } else {
     marker.icon = normalMarkerIcon(selected: false)
 }
 marker.zIndex = Int32(id) //your marker unique id
 marker.map = googleMapsView
```

And then you can get marker unique identifier in marker in `didTap` method to set different image or to perform other operation based on marker

```
extension POILocatorViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

        print("Marker Identifier = \(marker.zIndex)") //Get your marker your unique identifier here.
        return true
    }
}
```

Hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: One thing, do you know how to set a radius in GMaps that when the camera will go out that radius, a API call will be invoked with the updated coordinates?